# How to get query result into an array in NodeJs?

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, arrays

I have a page where I upload files into a server (local), and I save the data (name, root, size) of every file into a SQL db. I have to get an array with this information, in PHP i do this with:

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
```

Then i have to return this array to an HTML to see this values in a table, but i can´t get this array (I don´t know how).

This is my code in Node:

```
router.post('/uploadfile', upload.single('archivo'), async(req, res)=>{

let file_name = req.file.filename;
let file_root = req.file.path;
let file_size = Math.round(req.file.size /1024 /1024) + " Mb";
console.log(file_size);
const results = [];
await pool.query('INSERT INTO archivos (name, root, size) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [file_name, file_root, file_size], function (err, results, fields){
    //HERE I HAVE TO GET THE ARRAY
});

res.render('index.html', {results: results}); // HERE I HAVE TO PASS THE ARRAY

//console.log(archivo);
```

})

Comment: You want to get all the (name, root, size) tuples from your SQL table after insertion? I'm a bit confused as to what is your intent.

Comment: I want an array with EVERY file info (name, root, file) of the db. After this, I show the elements of this array un a html tablet.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your desired result/array. Should it be an array of objects, an array of arrays or just a flat array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only have to use, after a SELECT query, this:

```
results[0].name;
```

This is how i got the name of the first element. Thanks!